# How to Change the Appearance of a Swabfamily Capital A

Tags: fonts, symbols, typography, german

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor,oldgerm}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large
\swabfamily{How to Change the {\color{red}{A}}ppearance of a Swabfamily Capital {\color{red}{A}}}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I would like to have the `swabfamily` capital A---resemble, say, something like this:

[image]

QUESTION: Is this possible, and if so, how may I do this without changing the font?

Thank you.

Comment: isn't changing the shape of letters by definition changing the font?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Consider obtaining a round s by typing s: --- is that changing the font? I would like to know if there is a similar "fix" for the capital A.

Comment: well no, there isn't:-)  The U form for A seems to be a distinguishing feature of Schwabacher style. If you were using luatex and opentype you might have a possibility of variant glyphs hidden behind font features, but in a metafont/tfm font you just get what you can see.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Many thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was hoping to find a way around it with `pdflatex`. I can, however, compile with `lualatex`, in which case, I have other font alternatives with `fontspec` which accommodate a more usual looking A---such as the "A" I  posted. Thanks again.

Comment: Side remark: you are using `\color` wrong. This is a switch, not a command that takes two arguments. For this purpose you can use `\textcolor{color name}{text to be colored}`.

Comment: Contrary to what has been recommended, I believe that `yfonts` is much better than `oldgerm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define a virtual font. But don't do it: you get something really weird.

1. Copy `yswab.tfm` to a working directory and rename it to `temp.tfm`
2. Run `tftopl temp.tfm > ayswab.vpl`
3. Open `ayswab.vpl` with any text editor
4. Modify it to include `MAPFONT` and `MAP` directives for each character

Every character remains the same, except for `A`, that gets its metric information from `ygoth`. Here is what you'd get.

```
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.333334)
   (STRETCH R 0.166667)
   (SHRINK R 0.111112)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.463888)
   (QUAD R 1.000003)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.111112)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME yswab)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME ygoth)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C f O 204)
   (KRN C b R 0.043333)
   (KRN C h R 0.043333)
   (KRN C k R 0.043333)
   (KRN C l R 0.043333)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C s)
   (LIG O 72 O 215)
   (LIG C s O 201)
   (LIG C t O 202)
   (LIG C z O 32)
   (LIG C f O 203)
   (KRN C b R 0.111112)
   (KRN C h R 0.111112)
   (KRN C k R 0.111112)
   (KRN C l R 0.111112)
   (KRN C d R 0.057222)
   (KRN C i R 0.045278)
   (KRN C j R 0.045278)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 42)
   (LIG C a O 212)
   (LIG C e O 221)
   (LIG C o O 232)
   (LIG C u O 237)
   (LIG C s O 32)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 140)
   (LIG O 140 O 134)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 47)
   (LIG O 47 O 42)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 55)
   (LIG O 55 O 173)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 173)
   (LIG O 55 O 174)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 52)
   (LIG C a O 211)
   (LIG C e O 220)
   (LIG C o O 231)
   (LIG C u O 236)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 201)
   (KRN C b R 0.111112)
   (KRN C h R 0.111112)
   (KRN C k R 0.111112)
   (KRN C l R 0.111112)
   (KRN C d R 0.057222)
   (KRN C i R 0.045278)
   (KRN C j R 0.045278)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 203)
   (KRN C b R 0.043333)
   (KRN C h R 0.043333)
   (KRN C k R 0.043333)
   (KRN C l R 0.043333)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 204)
   (KRN C b R 0.043333)
   (KRN C h R 0.043333)
   (KRN C k R 0.043333)
   (KRN C l R 0.043333)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C c)
   (LIG C h O 205)
   (LIG C k O 206)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C r)
   (KRN C z R -0.031389)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C x)
   (KRN C z R -0.031389)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C l)
   (KRN C b R -0.039446)
   (KRN C f R -0.047223)
   (KRN C h R -0.039446)
   (KRN C k R -0.039446)
   (KRN C l R -0.039446)
   (KRN C m R -0.047223)
   (KRN C n R -0.047223)
   (KRN C t R -0.055555)
   (KRN C x R -0.047223)
   (KRN C y R -0.047223)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C L)
   (KRN C A R -0.094444)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C C)
   (KRN C I R -0.094444)
   (KRN C J R -0.094444)
   (KRN C K R -0.070833)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C D)
   (KRN C Y R -0.111112)
   (STOP)
   )
(CHARACTER O 20
   (CHARWD R 0.250002)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 20)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 21
   (CHARWD R 0.195501)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.1635)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 21)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 22
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 22)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 23
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 23)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 24
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.636806)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 24)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 25
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 25)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 26
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.592776)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 26)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 27
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 27)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 30
   (CHARWD R 0.444446)
   (CHARDP R 0.170138)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 30)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 32
   (CHARWD R 0.466669)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 32)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 41
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 41)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 42
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 42)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG C a O 212)
      (LIG C e O 221)
      (LIG C o O 232)
      (LIG C u O 237)
      (LIG C s O 32)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 43
   (CHARWD R 0.833336)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (CHARDP R 0.194443)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 43)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 45
   (CHARWD R 0.833336)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.055555)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 45)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 47
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 47)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG O 47 O 42)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 50
   (CHARWD R 0.38889)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 50)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 51
   (CHARWD R 0.38889)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 51)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 52
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 52)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG C a O 211)
      (LIG C e O 220)
      (LIG C o O 231)
      (LIG C u O 236)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 53
   (CHARWD R 0.777781)
   (CHARHT R 0.583334)
   (CHARDP R 0.083334)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 53)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 54
   (CHARWD R 0.305557)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 54)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 55
   (CHARWD R 0.250002)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 55)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG O 55 O 173)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 56
   (CHARWD R 0.305557)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 56)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 57
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 57)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 0
   (CHARWD R 0.493169)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 0)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 1
   (CHARWD R 0.333835)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 1)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 2
   (CHARWD R 0.495279)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 2)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 3
   (CHARWD R 0.377892)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 3)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 4
   (CHARWD R 0.493169)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 4)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 5
   (CHARWD R 0.340169)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 5)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 6
   (CHARWD R 0.442891)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 6)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 7
   (CHARWD R 0.489003)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 7)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 8
   (CHARWD R 0.484779)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 8)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 9
   (CHARWD R 0.442891)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C 9)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 72
   (CHARWD R 0.305557)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 72)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 74
   (CHARWD R 0.43889)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 74)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 75
   (CHARWD R 0.777781)
   (CHARHT R 0.374374)
   (CHARDP R -0.125626)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 75)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 77
   (CHARWD R 0.296114)
   (CHARHT R 0.47641)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 77)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C A
   (CHARWD R 0.619446)
   (CHARHT R 0.727751)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR C A)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C B
   (CHARWD R 0.795059)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C B)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C C
   (CHARWD R 0.591725)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C C)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C I R -0.094444)
      (KRN C J R -0.094444)
      (KRN C K R -0.070833)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C D
   (CHARWD R 0.790892)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C D)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C Y R -0.111112)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C E
   (CHARWD R 0.7112255)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C E)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C F
   (CHARWD R 0.579168)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.1635)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C F)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C G
   (CHARWD R 0.774115)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C G)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C H
   (CHARWD R 0.679781)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.142555)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C H)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C I
   (CHARWD R 0.746836)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.168779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C I)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C J
   (CHARWD R 0.746836)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.168779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C J)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C K
   (CHARWD R 0.746836)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C K)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C L
   (CHARWD R 0.60428)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C L)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C A R -0.094444)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C M
   (CHARWD R 1.013115)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C M)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C N
   (CHARWD R 0.853781)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C N)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C O
   (CHARWD R 0.723781)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C O)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C P
   (CHARWD R 0.686058)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C P)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C Q
   (CHARWD R 0.790892)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C Q)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C R
   (CHARWD R 0.738447)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C R)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C S
   (CHARWD R 0.799281)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C S)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C T
   (CHARWD R 0.683948)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C T)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C U
   (CHARWD R 0.683948)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C U)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C V
   (CHARWD R 0.7049465)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C V)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C W
   (CHARWD R 1.038281)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C W)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C X
   (CHARWD R 0.665113)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C X)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C Y
   (CHARWD R 0.7112255)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.13)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C Y)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C Z
   (CHARWD R 0.457558)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.062889)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C Z)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 133
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 133)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 134
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 134)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 135
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 135)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 136
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 136)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 137
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 137)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 140
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 140)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG O 140 O 134)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C a
   (CHARWD R 0.413501)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C a)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C b
   (CHARWD R 0.436557)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C b)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C c
   (CHARWD R 0.308725)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C c)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG C h O 205)
      (LIG C k O 206)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C d
   (CHARWD R 0.428225)
   (CHARHT R 0.641556)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C d)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C e
   (CHARWD R 0.315001)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C e)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C f
   (CHARWD R 0.301001)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C f)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG C f O 204)
      (KRN C b R 0.043333)
      (KRN C h R 0.043333)
      (KRN C k R 0.043333)
      (KRN C l R 0.043333)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C g
   (CHARWD R 0.482114)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.201279)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C g)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C h
   (CHARWD R 0.44917)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.185527)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C h)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C i
   (CHARWD R 0.250002)
   (CHARHT R 0.64341)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C i)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C j
   (CHARWD R 0.210169)
   (CHARHT R 0.64341)
   (CHARDP R 0.1635)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C j)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C k
   (CHARWD R 0.371613)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C k)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C l
   (CHARWD R 0.25828)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C l)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C b R -0.039446)
      (KRN C f R -0.047223)
      (KRN C h R -0.039446)
      (KRN C k R -0.039446)
      (KRN C l R -0.039446)
      (KRN C m R -0.047223)
      (KRN C n R -0.047223)
      (KRN C t R -0.055555)
      (KRN C x R -0.047223)
      (KRN C y R -0.047223)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C m
   (CHARWD R 0.69028)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C m)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C n
   (CHARWD R 0.468058)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C n)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C o
   (CHARWD R 0.463835)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C o)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C p
   (CHARWD R 0.480614)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.168779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C p)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C q
   (CHARWD R 0.459669)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.168779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C q)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C r
   (CHARWD R 0.363223)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C r)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C z R -0.031389)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C s
   (CHARWD R 0.233778)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C s)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG O 72 O 215)
      (LIG C s O 201)
      (LIG C t O 202)
      (LIG C z O 32)
      (LIG C f O 203)
      (KRN C b R 0.111112)
      (KRN C h R 0.111112)
      (KRN C k R 0.111112)
      (KRN C l R 0.111112)
      (KRN C d R 0.057222)
      (KRN C i R 0.045278)
      (KRN C j R 0.045278)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C t
   (CHARWD R 0.342224)
   (CHARHT R 0.58914)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C t)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C u
   (CHARWD R 0.463835)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C u)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C v
   (CHARWD R 0.489003)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C v)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C w
   (CHARWD R 0.728003)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C w)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C x
   (CHARWD R 0.363223)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.168779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C x)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C z R -0.031389)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C y
   (CHARWD R 0.44917)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.197057)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C y)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C z
   (CHARWD R 0.325445)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARDP R 0.185527)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C z)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 173
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARIC R 0.027779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 173)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (LIG O 55 O 174)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 174
   (CHARWD R 1.000003)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (CHARIC R 0.027779)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 174)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 175
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 175)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 176
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 176)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 201
   (CHARWD R 0.439336)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 201)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C b R 0.111112)
      (KRN C h R 0.111112)
      (KRN C k R 0.111112)
      (KRN C l R 0.111112)
      (KRN C d R 0.057222)
      (KRN C i R 0.045278)
      (KRN C j R 0.045278)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 202
   (CHARWD R 0.491002)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 202)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 203
   (CHARWD R 0.506558)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 203)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C b R 0.043333)
      (KRN C h R 0.043333)
      (KRN C k R 0.043333)
      (KRN C l R 0.043333)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 204
   (CHARWD R 0.506558)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 204)
      )
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C b R 0.043333)
      (KRN C h R 0.043333)
      (KRN C k R 0.043333)
      (KRN C l R 0.043333)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 205
   (CHARWD R 0.674561)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 205)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 206
   (CHARWD R 0.597003)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 206)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 211
   (CHARWD R 0.413501)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 211)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 212
   (CHARWD R 0.413501)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 212)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 215
   (CHARWD R 0.380002)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 215)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 220
   (CHARWD R 0.315001)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 220)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 221
   (CHARWD R 0.315001)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 221)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 231
   (CHARWD R 0.463835)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 231)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 232
   (CHARWD R 0.463835)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 232)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 236
   (CHARWD R 0.463835)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 236)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 237
   (CHARWD R 0.463835)
   (CHARHT R 0.463888)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 237)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 244
   (CHARWD R 0.43889)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 244)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 247
   (CHARWD R 0.466669)
   (CHARHT R 0.655939)
   (CHARDP R 0.177084)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR O 247)
      )
   )
```

Now run `vptovf ayswab.vpl`, which makes the files `ayswab.vf` and `ayswab.tfm`. Now make a test file

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% just fix the font declarations
\DeclareFontShape{LYG}{ygoth}{m}{n}{<->ygoth}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LY}{yfrak}{m}{n}{<->yfrak}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LY}{ysmfrak}{m}{n}{<->ysmfrak}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LY}{yswab}{m}{n}{<->yswab}{}
% the new font
\DeclareFontFamily{LY}{ayswab}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LY}{ayswab}{m}{n}{<->ayswab}{}
\def\swabdefault{ayswab}


\begin{document}

\textswab{How to Change the Appearance of a Swabfamily Capital A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `yfonts` is ***much*** better than `oldgerm`.

You need to have `ayswab.vf` and `ayswab.tfm` in the same directory as your document, or move them in a place that's looked for by the TeX system.